# VSCode debugger stdin\stdout not being shown

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a debugger for VSCode, is it possible to see what is going into and coming out of the debugger in VSC?

I thought stdout was going to be echoed to the Debug Console, but even with a simple application that writes a message and closes nothing appears.

Ideally I'd like to see everything including DAP messages? Is this available anywhere?

Comment: Ok, found my issue, `{"Category":1,"Message":"Stopping due to fatal error: NotImplementedException: No handler implemented for request type 'SetExceptionBreakpointsRequest'!"}` But I had to create an external textfile to log to, this doesn't feel optimal!!

Comment: Please don't use comments to add details. You can either [edit] your question or [post an answer](/help/self-answer) if you think it qualifies.

Comment: @wjandrea the comment is literally nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Oh, OK... maybe I misunderstood; I've never worked on this myself. Although, I don't understand why you posted a comment, if it's totally unrelated. Anyway, I'm just trying to help you put the info together sensibly, so if this doesn't help, ignore me.

Comment: The comment illustrates how hard it is to develop a debugger with VSCode, as there doesn't appear to be a way to see the VSCode DAP <-> Adaptor communication that occurs through stdin\out, which is what the question is asking about. If there is a way to see that, it would be very helpful, but I cannot find such an option, so does anyone know if it exists?